# Rails merge (and manual assignment) assigning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-5.1, rails-models

I am trying to create a model in a controller using strong params in Rails 5.1 (some things changed from previous for strong_params). However, when I inspect the params, the merged ones are NOT present and I am getting an ForbiddenAttributesError tracing back to the Model.new line below. The only thing in the Model is verify presence for all the attributes.

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController
  before_action :application_controller_action

  def create
    @model = Model.new(strong_params)
    if @model.valid?
      result = @model.save
    else
      render html: 'MODEL NOT VALID'
    end
    render html: 'DONE'
  end

  private
    def strong_params
      # attr_1 and attr_2 are set in the application controller and are available here.
      params.require(:model).permit(:name, :attribute_1, :attribute_2).merge(attribute_1: @attr_1, attribute_2: @attr_2)
      # Inserting the following two lines causes a ForbiddenAttributesError
      puts params.inspect  # DOES NOT INCLUDE @attr_1 and/or @attr_2
      return params
    end
```

I may be doing something wrong though because I've even tried putting the strong params into a model with the attributes (which I can inspect just before) and it still fails because the validation for attr_1 and attr_2 fail in the Model.

```
def create
  puts @user.inspect  (not nil)
  @model = Model.new(name: strong_params[:name], attribute_1: @attr_1, attribute_2: @attr_2)
```

UPDATE:

OK, I'm getting some weird errors from my troubleshooting. It seems the merge is not working correctly, though I'm sure it was at one point.

The first thing I checked was @attr_1 and @attr_2, they are definitely getting set.

For troubleshooting purposes, I've reduced the application before_action to this:

```
def application_before_action
  @attr_1 = Model.first
  @attr_2 = Model.last
```

With the code above, inspecting the params object and then returning it after the require().permit(), I am getting a ForbiddenAttributesError (no indication of what). If I remove those lines, I get a missing attributes error from the model indicating that @attr_1 and @attr_2 are missing.

**UPDATE 2**

Changed the title of the question, because I probably got confused during troubleshooting. I think the issue is just that the merge is assigning nil... but strangely so is the manual assignment suggested by (myself originally) and another answer here. The attributes keys are there, but they're getting assigned nil. Also, noticed my example was using a single Model, when there are actually two Models, Model1 and Model2. I am assigning the values from Model1 to Model2.

Here is a better demonstration of the error:

```
def create
    puts '0:'
    puts @model1.inspect
    puts '1:'
    puts strong_params.inspect
    @model2 = Model2.new(strong_params) do |m|
      m.user_id = @attr_1
      m.account_number = @attr_2
    end
    puts '3:'
    puts @model2.inspect

    if @model2.valid?
      result = @model2.save
      render html: 'SUCCESS' and return
    else
      render html: @model2.errors.full_messages and return
    end
end
```

Outputs in console:

```
0:
#<Model1 id: 29, attribute_1: 'test_value_1', attribute_2: 'test_value_2', created_at: "2018-08-15 03:55:08", updated_at: "2018-08-15 04:05:01">
1:
<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"test_name", "attribute_1"=>nil, "attribute_2"=>nil} permitted: true>
3:
#<Model2 id: nil, name: 'test_name', attribute_1: nil, attribute_2: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Obviously the nil id and timestamps are because the model has not been saved yet.

The html model2.errors.full_messages are: ["attribute_1 can't be blank", "attribute_2 can't be blank"]

**SOLUTION**

Coming from a pure ruby environment previously, I was mistaken about ActiveRecord default accessors for models. Removing the accessors seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: Where do `@attr_1` and `@attr_2` come from? Where is `:application_controller_action` defenition?

Comment: `strong_params` is just a regular method. It will not be executed until you call `strong_params` in your code. I think the problem is that the `application_controller_action` was never executed (or it hasn't set `@attr_1` and `@attr_2`). Have you consider that?

Comment: @user58446 I assume that you receive `name` in the controller, but how you get `@attr_1` and `@attr_2`. Are they also part of the request?

Comment: Sorry all, was busy troubleshooting. Please see update. attr_1 and attr_2 are not part of the request, they are set in a before_action (in the application controller) and are 'meant' to be added to the params hash. Strange it won't even let me create the object manually without just using the hash. Will disabling strong parameters stop this from happening?

Comment: Also, it seems strange to me that I have to permit something even though I am merging it. I would think Rails would differentiate between frontend params and backend params, if that makes sense.

Comment: @user58446 If you are overriding the attributes the second after permitting them there is no reason to permit them at all. I would leave them out. Furthermore you say `@attr_1` and `@attr_2` are definitely being set. However this does not mean they can't be `nil`. Even `Model.first` and `Model.last` can return `nil` if no entries are present. Have you checked the values of `@attr_1` and `@attr_2` before assigning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mucking about with the params hash you can just assign the odd values one by one:

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController
  before_action :application_controller_action

  def create
    @model = Model.new(strong_params) do |m|
      m.attribute_1 = @attr_1
      m.attribute_2 = @attr_2
    end

    if @model.valid?
      result = @model.save
    else
      render html: 'MODEL NOT VALID'
    end
    # don't do this it will just give a double render error
    render html: 'DONE'
  end

  private

   private
    def strong_params
      params.require(:model).permit(:name, :attribute_1, :attribute_2)
    end
end
```

In general this is a much more readable way to merge params with values from the session for example.

The reason your strong parameters method does not work is its just plain broken in every possible way. The main point is that you're not returning the whitelisted and merged params hash. You're returning the whole shebang.

You also seem under the faulty impression that `.require`, `.permit` and `.merge` alter the orginal hash - they don't - they return a new hash (well actually an ActionContoller::Parameters instance to be specific).

```
def strong_params
  # attr_1 and attr_2 are set in the application controller and are available here.
  permitted = params.require(:model).permit(:name, :attribute_1, :attribute_2)
        .merge(attribute_1: @attr_1, attribute_2: @attr_2)
  puts permitted.inspect
  permitted # return is implicit
end
```

Or just:

```
def strong_params
  # attr_1 and attr_2 are set in the application controller and are available here.
  params.require(:model).permit(:name, :attribute_1, :attribute_2)
        .merge(attribute_1: @attr_1, attribute_2: @attr_2)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your honesty: "The reason your strong parameters method does not work is its just plain broken in every possible way." I thought I was just following the example here plus a merge: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html. Regardless, your example with the block does not work. I am still getting valid? errors: ["attribute_1 can't be blank", "attribute_2 can't be blank"]. I can inspect the @attrs right before they're used and they are definitely set. And thanks for pointing out the error of me not assigning a value from require().permit().

Comment: Also, I do have attr_accessors set for all attributes involved... write for model attribute_1 and attribute_2, and read for the other.

Comment: See last update with a better demo of the problem. It's probably something simple, but I'm not sure where to investigate from here.

Comment: @user58446: "but I'm not sure where to investigate from here" - investigate actual values of @attr_1/@attr_2. Also they seem to be model instances and not simple primitives? In this case try persisting them like this: `m.attr1_id = @attr_1.id`. _Should_ do the same thing if all's good, but will crash if that object is nil.

Comment: You don't want to use `attr_accessor` for database backed attributes as it will overwrite the setters/getters created by ActiveRecord. I'm a bit lost on where to go from here as you just have a real mess and I don't really understand what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: @max: yeah, and fake attribute names don't help.

Comment: @max Well, that was it. I removed the attr_accessors and everything worked, but now I am more confused. I'm new to rails 2.5.1 so I'm not sure if there is something I'm missing, but I had added the accessors to resolve a previous error. Also, there seems to be significant information suggesting you need to write these in order to read/write to them. Lastly, I had written the correct accessors for the correct attributes, so they should have been able to read and write to the appropriate ones. Are the default accessors something I can view in the app? Is this a ruby vs. rails thing?...

Comment: There's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588803/understanding-ruby-on-rails-activerecord-model-accessors, but it doesn't entirely explain why mine were failing unless there is magic going on in the ActiveRecord default accessors (probably the case).

Comment: attr_accessor is plain ruby. It’s a meta-programming method that creates a setter and getter method. ActiveRecord does something similar based on the database schema. I would suggest you do some basic ruby tutorials like tryruby.org as this is pretty basic stuff

Comment: That's fine. I've done more than a few tutorials, but this must have been overlooked. I'm convinced there's things under rails' hood i will never understand. However, if all I have is an object, that is not saved to the db yet, I would expect a normal getter and setter, or the default provided by ruby's attr_reader/attr_writer to work.

Comment: It does. But I would really encourage you to ask a separate question that actually can be answered instead of making a bunch of assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to hash before merge

```
params.require(:model).permit(:name).to_h.merge(attribute_1: @attr_1, attribute_2: @attr_2)
```

You would have to be very sure that you are assigning non-user input though otherwise you are negating the purpose of strong parameters.